# Trying to access UWP's EmailMessage class from C++ results in "REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered" error

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp

My goal is to use [EmailMessage class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage) to let users of my desktop app [interact with the Windows Mail app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email) on Windows 10. As a test I'm trying the following from a stock C++ console app in Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <roapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "runtimeobject.lib")
#include <Windows.Services.Store.h>
#include <wrl.h>

using namespace ABI::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace ABI::Windows::Services::Store;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;
using namespace ABI::Windows::System;
using namespace ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace ABI::Windows::ApplicationModel::Email;


HRESULT hr;
if(SUCCEEDED(hr = RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED)))
{
    ComPtr<IEmailMessage> pEmlMsg;
    hr = RoGetActivationFactory(HStringReference(L"Windows.ApplicationModel.Email").Get(), __uuidof(pEmlMsg), &pEmlMsg);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) &&
        pEmlMsg)
    {
        //... keep going

    }
    else
        wprintf(L"ERROR: 0x%x RoGetActivationFactory\n", hr);

    RoUninitialize();
}
```

But my [`RoGetActivationFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/roapi/nf-roapi-rogetactivationfactory) call above always returns `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered`.

Any idea what am I missing there?

PS. I'm testing it on `Windows 10 v.1903 build 18362.239`.

Comment: The [EmailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage) type doesn't appear to have the [DualApiPartition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.dualapipartitionattribute) attribute. Are you sure it can be used in an application, that doesn't run in an app container?

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, it can be used, but need use  `RuntimeClass_Windows_ApplicationModel_Email_EmailMessage` instead `"Windows.ApplicationModel.Email"` and `RoGetActivationFactory` return `IActivationFactory` interface  but not `IEmailMessage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` *Class not registered* because "Windows.ApplicationModel.Email" really not registered. ( *look under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsRuntime\ActivatableClassId` key - no `Windows.ApplicationModel.Email` subkey here* )

you have 2 errors in code, instead self string "Windows.ApplicationModel.Email" - you need use `RuntimeClass_*` strings defined in some winrt header file. you need use

`RuntimeClass_Windows_ApplicationModel_Email_EmailMessage`

which is declared in *Windows.ApplicationModel.email.h*

then `RoGetActivationFactory` can not return `IEmailMessage` direct. it can return [`IActivationFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/activation/nn-activation-iactivationfactory?redirectedfrom=MSDN) interface (*You can get an `IActivationFactory` pointer by calling the `RoGetActivationFactory` function.* ) and then you need call [`IActivationFactory::ActivateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/activation/nf-activation-iactivationfactory-activateinstance) for get pointer to `IInspectable` and finally `QueryInterface` on it for get `IEmailMessage`

so better (if you need single instance of `IEmailMessage`) use [`RoActivateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/roapi/nf-roapi-roactivateinstance) here. code can be next

```
#include <winstring.h>
#include <roapi.h>
#include <Windows.ApplicationModel.email.h>

void CALLBACK ep(void*)
{
    if (0 <= RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED))
    {
        HSTRING_HEADER hsh;
        HSTRING activatableClassId;
        IInspectable* instance;
        ABI::Windows::ApplicationModel::Email::IEmailMessage* pEmlMsg;

        WindowsCreateStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_ApplicationModel_Email_EmailMessage, 
            _countof(RuntimeClass_Windows_ApplicationModel_Email_EmailMessage) - 1, 
            &hsh, &activatableClassId);

        if (0 <= RoActivateInstance(activatableClassId, &instance))
        {
            HRESULT hr = instance->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pEmlMsg));

            instance->Release();

            if (0 <= hr)
            {
                //...
                // some demo usage
                static const WCHAR body[] = L"-- demo --";
                WindowsCreateStringReference(body, _countof(body) - 1, &hsh, 
                         &activatableClassId);

                if (0 <= pEmlMsg->put_Body(activatableClassId))
                {
                    if (0 <= pEmlMsg->get_Body(&activatableClassId))
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%S\n", 
                           WindowsGetStringRawBuffer(activatableClassId, 0));

                        WindowsDeleteString(activatableClassId);
                    }
                }

                pEmlMsg->Release();
            }
        }

        RoUninitialize();
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Or, if you're a fan of [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt): `winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Email::EmailMessage msg{}; msg.Body(L"Not nearly enough boilerplate!");`. As an aside, `Windows.ApplicationModel.Email` is not registered, because it is not a type. It's a namespace.